# Calling exe from subprocess - xyv exe has stopped working

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am periodically receiving the below error from Tesseract OCR, although I have received it from other executables as well.

[image]

Is there a solution or way to better structure my `popen` calls to avoid this issue?

I am imagining a `subprocess.try_execute` which may catch this type of third party issue?

```
def run_tesseract(img_path,out_file='C:/temp/tesser_output'):

    image = Image.open(img_path)

    if len(image.split()) == 4:
        # In case we have 4 channels, lets discard the Alpha.
        # Kind of a hack, should fix in the future some time.
        r, g, b, a = image.split()
        image = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))

    image.save(img_path)

    command = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe" '+img_path+' '+ out_file +' -l eng'
    # print command
    res = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    tmp = res.stdout.read()

    try:
        f = open(out_file + '.txt', 'rb')
        out = f.read().decode('utf-8').strip()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        f.close()

    return out
```